# How I can use a foreground attribute in Jetpack Compose for example in a CardView?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

This attrubite I was using in xml. I want to use this foreground, when a user is cliking a view for example CardView.
Maybe I can use it via modifier or something like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to change the background of the cardview when the user clicks it, right?

```
    val isClicked = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val foregroundColor = if (isClicked.value) {
        Color.Black
    } else {
        Color.Transparent
    }

    Card(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(foregroundColor)
            .clickable {
                isClicked.value = !isClicked.value
                // Handle the click event here
            },
        elevation = 4.dp
    ) {
        // Content of the card
    }
```

Comment: Not at all. I want when a user clicks on a cardivew. The clicking foreground should be appeared

Comment: How I can use android:foreground attribute in Compose?

Comment: @Rustam try this, it would work